# JQgrid With Jsonp

Tags: jqgrid, jsonp

Does any one use JQGrid with JSONP. My Json in from seperate webapp and hence i am consuming using $.get with datatype JSONP.

I browsed through the JQgrid samples and documentation and there is no JSONP sample. I replaced the `url:'http://services.xxx.com/xxxx/json',datatype: "jsonp"` , On the document ready the jsonp request has been called and got the response with 200 OK padded data(In Firebug). But the grid rows are not getting populated.

Anything else i need to add or anyone got any workarounds for that. Currently i am using as local data type consuming the service and using as array type.

Regards,

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

It looks like even recently there were problems with `jsonp` - see this recent [forum thread](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jsonp-problem-cross-domain-call/&value=jsonp&type=1&include=1&search=1&ret=all).

Have you verified that the JSON that is returned is of the proper form that the jqGrid is expecting?